# How do I make an image spin in WPF while running a task in the background?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in which theres a start button that performs some web service calls, which return some results that I plot on a graph using oxyplot. I have an image on the UI that I would like to use as the "spinner" until the task has completed.

I'm able to use a button click routed event to spin my image but I want it to keep spinning until my web service calls are completed. Any suggestions?

```
 <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="capIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="capIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="capIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="capIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
```

And here is my  Button Click Method:

```
      private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!validateThreadCount())
        return;

        RunTimes.runTimes.Clear();
        //this.Plot.InvalidateFlag = 1;
        int threads = Convert.ToInt16(this.ThreadCount.Text);

        Task[] tasks =  new Task[threads];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            DealClient dealClient = new DealClient();
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dealClient.NewDeal(1));
            tasks[i] = t;
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        var points = new List<ScatterPoint>();
        for (int i = 0; i < RunTimes.runTimes.Count; i++)
        {
            points.Add(new ScatterPoint(RunTimes.runTimes[i].Milliseconds, i, 3));
        }

        this.pts.ItemsSource = points;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use an Async and Await method which handles the event. I don't have enough of your code to give you proper names but this is how I would approach the problem

```
Private async Task MethodThatHandlesEvent()
{
 await Task.Run(() => 
     {
         RunWebService();
            While(WebServiceIsRunning)
            {MakeImagesSpin();}
     });
}

Private async void MyButton_Click()
{
    await MethodThatHandlesEvent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped, now I just need to figure out how to spin the image from C#